# CSS Custom built checkbox not displaying within another checkbox on IE9

Tags: html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-9, customization

I have a list of checkboxes generated using this CSS code:

```
.regularCheckbox 
{
-webkit-appearance: none; /* WebKit */
-moz-appearance: none; /* Mozilla */
-o-appearance: none; /* Opera */
-ms-appearance: none; /* Internet Explorer */
-webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The problem is that on IE the standard checkbox is displaying within the one I have created.

http://jsfiddle.net/Naqmj/

How could I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: dont you need a `-ms-box-shadow` for ie ?

Comment: which IE version(s) are you testing with? Please specify when asking IE questions, because it makes a big difference.

Comment: @karthikr - no, you don't; IE9/10 can accept `box-shadow` unprefixed. But he does need to to at least provide the unprefixed version... IE *definitely* won't pick up the `-moz-` or `-webkit-` versions.

Comment: `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow` aren't needed either.

Comment: using IE9. Not sure why it still displays the standard checkbox

Comment: Custom checkboxes are extremely hard to use and unreliable. We had the same issue.  I would suggest using a Javascript or jQuery solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Javascript solution. 
I set up a jsFiddle example to use JS. That will work cross browser. IE you don't have access to the ms-appearance. There isn't one I don't think. Here is example [jsfiddle.net/JgJaU](http://jsfiddle.net/JgJaU). Yes it is a lot, but if you want cross browser compatibility, this is what it takes.

I did find this example too. Looks promising but it makes use of sprite images.
http://csscheckbox.com/.  CSS only checkboxes.

The only thing with this is that anything lower than IE9 is going to break. So the Javascript solutions is going to be your best bet.

Looks like this:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {display:none;}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
                        padding-left:20px;
                        height:15px; 
                        display:inline-block;
                        line-height:15px;
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        background-position: 0 0;
                        font-size:15px;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                        cursor:pointer;
                    }

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
                        background-position: 0 -15px;
                    }

                    .css-label{
                        background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/dark-check-green.png);
                    }
```

HTML:

```
  <input id="demo_box_1" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="demo_box_1" name="demo_lbl_1" class="css-label">Option #1</label>
                <!-- Checkbox powered by CssCheckbox.com -->

                <input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                <label for="demo_box_2" name="demo_lbl_2" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
                <!-- Checkbox powered by CssCheckbox.com -->

                <input id="demo_box_3" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="demo_box_3" name="demo_lbl_3" class="css-label">Option #3</label>
                <!-- Checkbox powered by CssCheckbox.com -->
```